# jQuery Mobile Button radius css

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

How do I make a button radius be specific to a theme... I'm using 3 themes and I need the below global button css code to only apply to theme **B**

```
.ui-btn-corner-all {
    -moz-border-radius:                 .3em /*{global-radii-buttons}*/;
    -webkit-border-radius:              .3em /*{global-radii-buttons}*/;
    border-radius:                  .3em /*{global-radii-buttons}*/;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just be sure to place the following after the JQM stylesheet.

```
[data-theme=b].ui-btn-corner-all {
    -moz-border-radius:             .3em;
    -webkit-border-radius:          .3em;
    border-radius:                  .3em;
}​
```

Comment: so this goes in the html file and not the jquery.mobile-1.1.0.css file?

Comment: Make your own external css file and place it after the jquery.mobile-1.1.0.css file. You are basically overriding their style. Since its more specific I don't think it matters if its before or after but that is what I would do anyway.

Comment: And what if you don't whant to modify the border for all the data-theme=b buttons, but just some of them?

Comment: Just get more specific with your css. Example: .your-class [data-theme=b].ui-b.....

Answer (score 0):

This work for no corners:

```
data-corners="false"
```